# fold_column when using h2o.grid in R

Tags: r, h2o

Using the fold_column parameter leads to an error when using h2o.grid for any algorithm / method. Does anybody know why that is the case? h2o.grid works when I just use nfolds and the estimation - not using the grid function - also works when fold_column is used, but not when I combin h2o.grid and fold_column even though is should work (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html)

```
library(h2o)

#create random data
N = 1000

y = rnorm(N)
x1 = y + rnorm(N)
x2 = -y + 0.5*rnorm(N)
x3 = rnorm(N)

Data = data.table(y = y, 
                  x1 = x1, 
                  x2 = x2, 
                  x3 = x3, 
                  Split = rep(1:5, N/5), 
                  Weight = runif(N))
setkey(Data, Split)


#h2o
h2o.init(
  nthreads=-1,            ## -1: use all available threads
  max_mem_size = "4G")    ## specify the memory size for the H2O cloud
h2o.removeAll() # Clean slate - just in case the cluster was already running


bla = h2o.assign(as.h2o(Data), "bla.hex")


#make simple grid
Grid = list(ntrees = seq(1, 5, by=1))


#not working: grid with fold_column
GridResult = h2o.grid("gbm", 
                      x = c("x1", "x2", "x3"), 
                      y = "y",
                      training_frame = bla,
                      hyper_params = Grid,
                      keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                      weights_column = "Weight",
                      fold_column = "Split"
)

#working: grid with nfolds
GridResult = h2o.grid("gbm", 
                      x = c("x1", "x2", "x3"), 
                      y = "y",
                      training_frame = bla,
                      hyper_params = Grid,
                      keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                      weights_column = "Weight",
                      nfolds = 5
)
```

My key information is
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
h2o_3.8.2.6

Error:

```
[2018-03-08 14:14:38] failure_details: NA 
[2018-03-08 14:14:38] failure_stack_traces: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hex.ModelBuilder.nFoldWork(ModelBuilder.java:209)
    at hex.ModelBuilder.computeCrossValidation(ModelBuilder.java:224)
    at hex.ModelBuilder.trainModelNested(ModelBuilder.java:186)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch.startBuildModel(GridSearch.java:329)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch.buildModel(GridSearch.java:311)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch.gridSearch(GridSearch.java:215)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch.access$000(GridSearch.java:69)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch$1.compute2(GridSearch.java:136)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1194)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Comment: do you realize that you are using release Turchin (3.8.2.6) - 5/24/2016 ? did you try updating h2o package to the latest?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in the latest stable version of H2O, 3.18.0.4.  Please upgrade your H2O package and in the future, please always try your code on the latest stable release of H2O before posting here. Thx!

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am aware of that. I am working for an instituation where very frequent updates are not possible and I am therefore using the hold version and old help pdfs. But I understand that reproduction is not possible under that circumstances and I am going to ask for updates at first. Thanks.